# Infinite dimensional spaces other than functional spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, soft-question, hilbert-spaces, banach-spaces, normed-spaces

"Functional analysis" is the study of infinite dimensional spaces equipped with inner product, norm, topology...etc. The most interesting spaces are the spaces of functions/operators and sequences.

I don't know if there's "another kind" of infinite dimensional spaces other than space of functions/operators/sequences which is interesting.

Comment: $\mathbb{R}$ as a vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$ is quite an interesting set.

Comment: Well, the dual spaces of natural function spaces are certainly interesting. And spaces of continuous maps from one natural space to another... I do think that the importance of "functional analysis" is mostly that it _does_ usually have close connections to and implications for spaces of functions ... thus, "calculus"!

Answer (score 4):

In fact [all normed spaces are subspaces of some function spaces](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/140101/for-banach-space-there-is-a-compact-topological-space-so-that-the-banach-space-i). This could be the reason why functional analysis has its name.

Answer (score 3):

One example might be $M(K)$, the space of all regular Borel measures on $K$ of finite variation, where $K$ is compact space. This space arises as the dual of $C(K)$.

Answer (score 2):

$\mathbb{R}$ is an infinite dimensional vector spaces over $\mathbb{Q}$, but it is not an Hilbert space. 
You can see that all the axioms for a vector space are verified if you define the sum of two ''vectors" as the usual sum of real numbers and the product for a scalar $q \in \mathbb{Q}$ as the usual product.

This space has an infinite dimensional [Hamel basis](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HamelBasis.html).

And, obviously, any $\mathbb{R}^n$ is finite dimensional over $\mathbb{R}$ but infinite dimensional over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: But $\mathbb{R}$ as a vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$ is not an object of study of Functional Analysis as we know that the basic requirement is that the underlying field be $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: I agree, but you asked  abot  "another kind" of infinite dimensional spaces other than space of functions/operators/sequences which is interesting. And, in my opinion, $\mathbb{R}^n$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ are interesting. Don't you agree? :)

Comment: yes I agree that it is interesting and quite terrifying(to me) but my only point is that it is of no use in Functional analysis...Nevertheless you are absolutely right for it being interesting...

Answer (score 2):

An extremely interesting Banach space that admittedly is a sequence space but is not frequently discussed is Tsirelson's space. This is a reflexive Banach space that contains no isomorphic copy of $c_{0}$ or of $\ell_{p}$ for $p\in[1,\infty)$. More commonly, one deals with the dual space $\mathcal{T}$ of Tsirelon's original construction which is, as formulated by Figiel and Johnson, the completion of the set $c_{00}$ of finitely-supported scalar seqeunces with respect to the implicitly defined norm:
\begin{multline*} 
\|x\|_{\mathcal{T}}=\max\left\{\|x\|_{\infty},\frac{1}{2}\sup\left\{\sum_{i=1}^{N}\|E_{i}x\|_{\mathcal{T}}\;\middle\vert\; N\in\mathbb{N} \right.\right. \\ \left.\left. \phantom{\sum_{i=1}^{N}}\text{ and } \{N\}\leq E_{1}<E_{2}<\ldots <E_{N}\right\}\right\} \qquad x=(x_{j})_{j=1}^{\infty}\in c_{00}
\end{multline*}
where $E_{i}\subset\mathbb{N}$ is finite, $E_{i}x=\sum_{j\in E_{i}}x_{j}e_{j}$, and the notation $E<F$ means that $\max(E)<\min(F)$ for subsets $E,F\subset\mathbb{N}$. The Banach space $\mathcal{T}$ is the basis (no pun intended) of numerous counterexamples in Banach space theory and gives rise to a number of variants which have curious properties (such as being arbitrarily distortable).

Answer (score 1):

Algebraists study many algebras which are of infinite dimension over their ground field, like [Universal Enveloping Algebras](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_enveloping_algebra), [Kac-Moody Algebras](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kac%E2%80%93Moody_algebra), [Weyl Algebras](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weyl_algebra), ...