# All infinite dimensional vector spaces with a countable basis are space of sequences or functions?

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-spaces

I'm searching a proof that every infinite dimensional vector space that has a countable basis ([Schauder basis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schauder_basis)), can be represented as a space of functions or sequences.

All vector spaces of this type that I know are really function or sequence spaces, or spaces of linear operators that, ultimately, are space of functions. But I never find a representation theorem that states that there are not other possibilities.

What I find is a theorem similar to [Artin–Wedderburn](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artin%E2%80%93Wedderburn_theorem) theorem for rings, that say us that semisimple rings are isomorphic to a product of finitely many matrix rings. There is some similar result that tell us what are the possible representations of vector spaces?

Note: there is a similar question here [Infinite dimensional spaces other than functional spaces](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1213428/infinite-dimensional-spaces-other-than-functional-spaces/1213461#1213461) but i think that it's not a duplicate because here I ask explicitly about vector spaces with countable basis.

Comment: You don't need to separate "functions" and "sequences" since a sequence is just a function whose domain is $\mathbb N$.

Comment: Yes, I agree. I separated only to be more explicit.

Comment: See this: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/140101/for-banach-space-there-is-a-compact-topological-space-so-that-the-banach-space-i

Comment: @JoshKenda: This is an interesting result, but not completely fits my question.

Comment: I think it can be adapted to suit your question. If you have a Schauder basis, then you must be working in a normed vector space (or you have to at least specify a topology in which your infinite sums can converge). So we have more than just vector space data to work with. Complete V with respect to its norm, take the canonical embedding of V's completion into its double dual, and then restrict that embedding to V. This identifies V with a space of continuous functions on a compact Hausdorff space. Isn't this what you want? Or did I misunderstand?

Comment: Ah. You must mean Schauder in the TVS sense rather than the Wikipedia definition. Got it. Can't help you in the general case. :)

Comment: I'm tinking about your comment. What do you means by TVS? Topological vector spaces?

Comment: Right. If you have a normed vector space, then my answer addresses your question. But you can still define Schauder bases with more general topological vector spaces. And I can't help you there. :)